# No "setup" function in the turtle module to change window size

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've been trying to change the size of the window that opens up when running my code.

I checked and saw people have been using:

```
screen.setup (width=x_val, height=y_val, startx=start_x, starty=start_y)
```

When I tried using it in my own code it doesn't even show as an option:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work as you're calling the screen method `.setup()` on a turtle instance.  Try this approach instead:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(300, 300)

tortoise = Turtle()

# ...

screen.exitonclick()
```